# MVC, HTML with ASP.NET Linking

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I want to use custom buttons in my MVC Page. I am designing the View Page.

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage" %>
```

MainMenu

```
<!-- Main Menu Div-->
<form id="MainMenu" runat="server">
 <div id="MainMenuFirstView">
<h2 class="LabelHeader">

<b>
     &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp <u>View </u>
 </b>

</h2>
<h3>
<asp:Button ID="btnHome" runat ="server" Text ="Home" Width="15%" CssClass="Button" SkinID= "Button" />
<asp:Button ID="btnNewUser" runat ="server" Text ="Add New User" Width="15%" CssClass="Button"/>
<asp:Button ID="btnAmendUser" runat ="server" Text ="Amend User" Width="15%"  CssClass="Button"  />
<asp:Button ID="btnAddNewAbsence" runat ="server" Text ="Add New Absence" Width="15%"  CssClass="Button" />
<asp:Button ID="btnAmendAbsence" runat ="server" Text ="Amend Absence" Width="15%"  CssClass="Button"  />
<asp:Button ID="btnAddJobRole" runat ="server" Text ="Add Job Role" Width="15%"  CssClass="Button" />
<asp:Button ID="btnAmendJobRole" runat ="server" Text ="Amend Job Role" Width="15%"  CssClass="Button" />
<asp:Button ID="btnAddShiftEvent" runat ="server" Text ="Add Shift Event" Width="15%"  CssClass="Button" />
<asp:Button ID="btnAmendShiftEvent" runat ="server" Text ="Amend Shift Event" Width="15%"  CssClass="Button" />
<asp:Button ID="btnAddDMICase" runat ="server" Text ="Add DMI Case" Width="15%" CssClass="Button"  />
<asp:Button ID="btnAmmendDMICase" runat ="server" Text ="Amend DMI Case" Width="15%"  CssClass="Button" />    
</h3>
</div>
</form>
</asp:Content>
```

If I want to use this a CSS file, How do I link it in this page?

Like: `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />`

In which part of the page I have to use this?

Comment: Normally you'd put the <link rel... in the <head> section of your website. In this case, if possible add if to your Site.Master masterpage.

Comment: As a side note, unless there are specific reasons to use `<b>` tags, I'd use `<strong>` tags instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add the stylesheet reference directly to your master page and it will be applied to all pages like

```
<head>
  <!-- ...other stuff here  -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
</head>
```

Or if you want to be able to add different stylesheets to different pages then you can add a content placeholder to your master page

```
<head>
  <!-- ...other stuff here  -->
  <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="Styles" runat="server"></asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</head>
```

Then on your view page use

```
<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderID="Styles" runat="server">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
</asp:Content>
```

Also note that in MVC you do not use  controls or other WebForms server controls.  You should use HtmlHelpers or HTML directly.

```
<button id="btnHome" class="button">Home</button>
```